# C Language - how to ensure a constant format is kept while reading multiple input files?

Tags: c, whitespace, string-formatting

I'm trying to indent my string output for the below code but for some reason my variables keep being pulled from the files with ranging lengths of noise or space (I'm not to sure).[image][image]

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int
main (void)
{
FILE *data_File;
FILE *lake_File;
FILE *beach_File;
char fileName[10], lake_Table[15],beach_Table[15];  /*.txt file names */
int lake_data=0,lake_x=0, beach_x=0, nr_tests=0;    /* variables for the file july08.txt */
int province_data=0,prv_x=0;        /* variables for the file Lake Table.txt */
int beach_data=0,bch_x=0;           /* variables for the file Beach Table.txt*/
char province[30] = ""; /*variable for the file Lake Table.txt*/
char beach[20]="",beach1[20];   /*variable for the data within the file Beach Table.txt*/
int j;
double status, ecoli_lvl;
printf ("Which month would you like a summary of? \nType month followed by date (i.e: july05): ");
gets(fileName);
/*Opening the files needed for the program*/
data_File = fopen (fileName, "r");
lake_File = fopen ("Lake Table.txt", "r");
beach_File = fopen ("Beach Table.txt", "r");
printf ("\n  Lake           Beach          Average E-Coli Level     Recommendation\n");
dashes();

/* july08.txt file*/
fscanf (data_File, "%d", &lake_x);
fscanf (data_File, "%d", &beach_x);
lake_data = fscanf (data_File, "%d", &nr_tests);

/* Lake Table.txt file*/
province_data = fscanf (lake_File, "%d", &prv_x);
fgets (province,30,lake_File);

/* Beach Table.txt file*/
beach_data = fscanf (beach_File, "%d", &bch_x);
fgets (beach,20,beach_File);
status = (double) 0;

while (lake_data != EOF)
{
    while (province_data > 0)
    {
        if (lake_x == prv_x)
        {
            province_data = 0;
            while (beach_data > 0)
            {
                if (beach_x == bch_x)
                {
                    beach_data = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    beach_data = fscanf (beach_File, "%d", &bch_x);
                    fgets (beach,30,beach_File);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            province_data = fscanf (lake_File, "%d", &prv_x);
            fgets (province,30,lake_File);
        }
        if (province[strlen(province)-1] =='\n')
            province[strlen(province)-1] ='\0';
        else if (beach[strlen(beach)-1] =='\n')
            beach[strlen(beach)-1] ='\0';
    }
    for (j=1; j<=nr_tests; ++j)
    {
        fscanf (data_File, "%lf", &ecoli_lvl);
        status = status + ecoli_lvl;
    }

    printf ("%s\t%s\t\t%.2f", province, beach, status);

    /* Lake Table.txt file*/
    rewind (lake_File);
    province_data = fscanf (lake_File, "%d", &prv_x);
    fgets (province,30,lake_File);

    /* Beach Table.txt file*/
    rewind (beach_File);
    beach_data = fscanf (beach_File, "%d", &bch_x);
    fgets (beach,20,beach_File);

    fscanf (data_File, "%d", &lake_x);
    fscanf (data_File, "%d", &beach_x);
    lake_data = fscanf (data_File, "%d", &nr_tests);
    printf ("\n");
    status = (double) 0;
}
fclose (data_File);
return (0);
}
```

How do i get to align the strings under each column? Keep in mind this is beginner programing in C. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, if you want fixed-with columns of output, then use e.g. `"%-20s"` format to print a left-justified string padded up to 20 characters wide. See e.g. [this `printf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). As for your problems, you might want to run your program in a debugger and step through the code line by line to see what happens and what data is read and stored.

Comment: I originally couldn't figure it out last time for the code you mention (too tired i suppose). but now that's what i've been needing. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement,

```
 if (province[strlen(province)-1] =='\n')
        province[strlen(province)-1] ='\0';
    else if (beach[strlen(beach)-1] =='\n')// here
        beach[strlen(beach)-1] ='\0';
```

In this statement you have to make the null character instead of new line. Because
you are printing like this.

```
printf ("%s\t%s\t\t%.2f", province, beach, status);
```

Change the statement into like this,

```
if (province[strlen(province)-1] =='\n')
        province[strlen(province)-1] ='\0';
if (beach[strlen(beach)-1] =='\n')
        beach[strlen(beach)-1] ='\0';
```

so if the new line is placed in the beach string, output will be like your output. After printing the beach newline will printed and two tabs `\t\t`. This is the reason you are getting the output in next line. Then as like said in comments, use the `%-s` for padding the spaces. It will give you the formatted print.

Comment: You're my lifesaver my man! I couldn't figure out how to use the %-s code last night (I was way to tired I suppose) but now that I did make the changes you said (made sense since I was only clearing the beach variable if the first condition was false) everything is working beautiful! Thanks for all the help. Cheers!